# Firefox windows content is larger than the actual window size after disconnecting from a larger second monitor on a Lenovo laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, firefox, display, 22.04, lenovo

On a Lenovo P15s laptop / Ubuntu 22.04 (5.15.0-47-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux) / Firefox 104.0.1 (64-bit):

when I connect to a docking station to benefit from a second monitor which is larger than the Laptop's one, after disconnecting from that station, the *content* of the Firefox window still fit the larger monitor display, and doesn't adapt to the new window size.
Whatever I do.

Therefore, I'm facing a situation where the content of web pages is shifted on the right, and I cannot access whatever is after the right border of the Firefox window, even if I make it full screen. But this does not only apply to web pages content; the rightmost part of my tabs and the main FF menu bars are also not accessible. Same goes with the bottom part; I also can't access the content of the last 200-300 pixels. Firefox seems stuck with the larger resolution of that second monitor.

I'm forced to reboot Firefox to make the content actually follow and adapt to the actual Firefox window size.

How could I debug/fix that?

More info:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND16 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND17 connected 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   2560x1440     59.91*+
   1920x1440     59.90  
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   2048x1152     59.90  
   1920x1080     59.88  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Comment: How you see Firefox behaving is perfectly natural. How would the app that is already running know you changed the monitor.

Comment: Well, to me it's not natural at all. The app shouldn't care about "monitors"; it only has to "think" about fitting its own content to its own window, regardless of a monitor, isn't it? I mean, even with no monitor plugged, a Firefox window could still "exist". And actually, Firefox was perfectly resizing itself on Ubuntu 18.04, whatever extra monitor(s) I plugged/unplugged. I'm really newly facing this bug on 22.04.

Comment: If it is a bug it is not an OS bug but a Firefox bug.

Comment: Any new information on this, as I am facing the same issue, but don't have the requirements to comment, but on the research made when move the Firefox window to the Second monitor which is larger than the current default it resizes correctly. Thus it seems firefox is trying to resize onto the larger screen

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue on macOS.
I have Firefox windows open on both of my 4K (3840x2160) monitors, then I change one of the monitors to 2560x1440 and Firefox displays its windows on that monitor as 3840x2160.
Moving a window from the smaller to the larger monitor then back again changes nothing.
Closing and re-opening all windows on the smaller monitor changes nothing.
Quitting and restarting Firefox changes nothing.
Firefox still thinks the smaller monitor is at the larger resolution.
This is brain-dead.